# Is a great-grandchild an "encore" descendent?

Tags: etimología, definiciones, parentesco

"Nieto" is a grandson (and "Nieta" presumably a granddaughter).

"Bisnieto" is a great-grandson (and "bisnieta" no doubt a great-granddaughter).

"Bis" means "encore".

So is a grandchild an "encore" grandchild?

I think of an "encore" that a musical band may perform as a sort of a "bonus" set (one ore more "extra" songs to finish a concert, if all has gone well, or to reward an appreciative audience).

Is the sense of "bisnieto" that, although one may expect to have children and grandchildren - nothing too unusual in that - to have great-grandchildren is something of a "bonus"?

Comment: What is the difference between a grandson and a grandchild?

Comment: A grandchild can be either male or female.

Comment: Then the correct answer is NOT bisnieto...

Comment: No; how could it be? That would not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bis, bi* means *two* or *twice*; *bisnieto* means, roughly, *twice the grandchild*. I don't think *bisnieto* has the meaning of a bonus.

From [Definiciona](https://definiciona.com/bisnieto/):

> Este vocablo en su etimología esta compuesto del prefijo latino “bi” dos y del latín popular “nepta”, a su vez del latín “neptis” que quiere decir nieto.

Answer (score 1):

Bis comes from the Latin meaning twice. So in some countries you shout it to get what in the UK you would shout encore for. So it is twice a grand child not an encore grand child.

Comment: Do you have some examples of countries?  That is very interesting.

Comment: Well @aparente001 I suspect this is a bit off-topic, but French, Italian, Portuguese seem to use the word bis in that sense.